# "Error debug" in the moment when I set a new formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert a formula in a cell but Appear an error when I set my own function. Anyone can explain me which it's the reason.

Thank

```
Sheets("market").Select 
Range("M2").Select 
ActiveCell.Formula ="=IF(DatoInformado(Bread!H9);0;1)"
```

Comment: Does `.FormulaLocal` instead of `.Formula` work?

Comment: When setting a range's `Formula` property from VBA you need to use the "US" comma separator.